# Transferring UITableView Section to Another TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am currently set up to transfer section 1 of my tableview to another tableView. This is done by moving the didSelectRow: rows. However, the issue is that when I attempt to move the section when every row is selected (and there is nothing in section 0) it crashes with an index is beyond bounds error.

I am using a boilerPlate code for my sectionHeaders due to section 1 header changing back to section 0 header when all items selected in section 1. I believe this is what is causing the index to be out of bounds error, but am not sure how to correct it.

My sections are set up as:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    let numberOfSections = frc.sections?.count
    return numberOfSections!
}

//Table Section Headers
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{
    let sectionHeader = "Items Needed - #\(frc.sections![section].numberOfObjects)"
    let sectionHeader1 = "Items in Cart - #\(frc.sections![section].numberOfObjects)"
    if (frc.sections!.count > 0) {
        let sectionInfo = frc.sections![section]
        if (sectionInfo.name == "0") { 
            return sectionHeader
        } else {
            return sectionHeader1
        }
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

with my didSelectRow and cells as:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SLTableViewCell

    //assign delegate
    cell.delegate = self

    let items = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! List
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    cell.cellLabel.text = "\(items.slitem!) - Qty: \(items.slqty!)"
    cell.cellLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(25)
    moveToPL.hidden = true

    if (items.slcross == true) {
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        cell.cellLabel.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        cell.cellLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)
        self.tableView.rowHeight = 50
        moveToPL.hidden = false

    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = .None
        cell.cellLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        cell.cellLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(25)
        self.tableView.rowHeight = 60
        moveToPL.hidden = true
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let items = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! List

    if (items.slcross == true) {
        items.slcross = false
    } else {
        items.slcross = true
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Is this my issue or is something else causing this?

Edit:
I tried changing my function in charge of moving items from this:

```
@IBAction func moveToPantry(sender: AnyObject) {

    let sectionInfo = self.frc.sections![1]
    let objectsToAppend = sectionInfo.objects as! [List]
    for item in objectsToAppend {
        item.slist = true
        item.slcross = false
        item.plist = false
        item.slitem = item.pitem
        item.slqty = item.pqty
        item.sldesc = item.pdesc
        item.slprice = item.pprice
        item.slminqty = item.pminstepperlabel

    }
}
```

to:

```
@IBAction func moveToSL(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (frc.sections!.count > 0) {
    let sectionInfo = self.frc.sections![1]
          if (sectionInfo.name == "0") {
    let objectsToAppend = sectionInfo.objects as! [List]
    for item in objectsToAppend {
        item.slist = true
        item.slcross = false
        item.plist = false
        item.slitem = item.pitem
        item.slqty = item.pqty
        item.sldesc = item.pdesc
        item.slprice = item.pprice
        item.slminqty = item.pminstepperlabel
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is still throwing the error. It will move all the objects as long as section 0 isn't empty. Any more help in figuring this out would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your table view methods look fine. But it seems as though your `frc` variable would be deleting items from its arrays if the user selects it? I would recommend creating a new object to store the items the user has selected. Also doing a check to make sure the section isn't empty before trying to access it. such as `frc.sections!.count > 0` like you used in `titleForHeader` but everywhere you access the frc's indexes as in `didSelectRow`so you don't get out of bounds at index errors.

Comment: I edited my question with the code from the move button. Hopefully it'll make more sense. When the item is created it goes into section 0 with item cross = false. didselectrow: changes false to true and moves to section 1. then button should move section 1 to section 0 of the other tableView. it works just as long as there is an object in section 0 of tableView items are moving from. if there is nothing in section 0 index becomes out of bounds.